# elasticsearch sub-aggregations failing

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

On ES 2.2 I am trying the following query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "startDate": {
            "gt": "2016-07-01"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "numbera": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "numbera",
        "size": 0,
        "aggs": {
          "some": {
            "avg": {
              "field": "callDuration"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which gives the following error:

```
{
    "type": "search_parse_exception",
    "reason": "Unknown key for a START_OBJECT in [numbera]: [aggs].",
    "line": 20,
    "col": 18
}
```

I am at a loss, what is wrong with that query?

Removing the sub aggregation from the query gives me a proper result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nested `aggs` should be at the same level as `"terms": {...}`, not nested under it.

```
"aggs": {
  "numbera": {
    "terms": {
      "field": "numbera",
      "size": 0
    },
    "aggs": {
      "some": {
        "avg": {
          "field": "callDuration"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```